# Neo4j: disintermediating nodes

Tags: transactions, neo4j

I have a graph in Neo4J (Community version 2.1.6) that has a certain type of node, `TypeX`, that I want to remove all instances of, replacing its position with edges that preserve the existing connectivity.  Conceptually, this is like `TypeX` representing a multi-edge, and replacing it with the fully-connected subgraph of nodes connected to that multi-edge.

I attempted to use the following Cypher query, but I run into transaction troubles:

```
MATCH (c)-[e1]-(a:TypeX)-[e2]-(b)
CREATE UNIQUE c-[:CONNECTED_TO]-b
DELETE a, e1, e2;
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Relationships created: 18276
Nodes deleted: 7677
Relationships deleted: 13546
1571 ms
TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction
```

I guess this is because some `TypeX` nodes may be connected to other `TypeX` nodes, and the operations on two such neighboring nodes conflict with each other.

Is there a way to run a query like this, in a "greedy" fashion so that `TypeX` nodes are picked off one-by-one and eliminated?  I'm fairly new to Neo4J so there might be something obvious I'm overlooking.

[UPDATE]: Here's some example data:

```
CREATE (a:Foo {id:"a"}), (b:TypeX {id:"b"}), (c:Bar {id:"c"}),
       (d:TypeX {id:"d"}), (e:TypeX {id:"e"}), 
       (f:Foo {id:"f"}), (g:Foo {id:"g"}),
       a-[:Z]->b-[:Z]->c<-[:Z]-d<-[:Z]-e,
       f-[:Z]->e<-[:Z]-g<-[:Z]-f
```

[image: before]

After the operation, I should have the following graph:

```
CREATE (a:Foo {id:"a"}), (c:Bar {id:"c"}),
       (f:Foo {id:"f"}), (g:Foo {id:"g"}),
       a-[:Z]->c,
       f-[:Z]->c<-[:Z]-g
```

[image: after]

(Edge directions are arbitrary, this is essentially an undirected graph.)

Comment: Could `c` and `b` be `TypeX` nodes, or are they always other labels/labeless?

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem.  Since it works one path at a time, if a TypeX node connects a node two two other nodes separately then it can't delete that TypeX node because it's still connected to whichever one it's not working on

Comment: @BrianUnderwood - they can also be `TypeX` nodes, which I think is the crux of the problem.

Comment: I edited to give some example data, with the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're basically right about the TypeX nodes being deleted before they are completely removed.

This may work, but I doubt it:

```
MATCH (c)-[e1]-(a:TypeX)-[e2]-(b)
CREATE UNIQUE c-[:CONNECTED_TO]-b
WITH a
MATCH (c)-[e1]-(a)-[e2]-(b)
DELETE a, e1, e2;
```

Otherwise I think you'd want to do two queries:

```
MATCH (c)-[e1]-(a:TypeX)-[e2]-(b)
CREATE UNIQUE c-[:CONNECTED_TO]-b;

MATCH (c)-[e1]-(a:TypeX)
WHERE NOT(type(e1) = 'CONNECTED_TO') AND NOT(c:TypeX)
DELETE a, e1;
```

Comment: You can also move the create unique last. after the delete.

Comment: Unfortunately neither seems to work.  The first query does run, but it breaks connectivity - the result should have the same number of connected components as the original.  The second query fails with the same transaction problem as in my original query.

Comment: Perhaps if I could first enumerate all paths that go from a non-`TypeX` node, through any number `1..` of `TypeX` nodes, ending at a different non-`TypeX` node - then I could add unique edges to all these node pairs, and afterwards I'd be free to delete all the `TypeX` nodes and their edges.

Comment: Does the first query of the second code block that I showed preserve the connectivity?  If so you may want to try the second query again with my edits.  I think if you just `MATCH` on one relationship and delete those you should be able to do it without a transaction issue.

Comment: It still has the same transaction issue upon deletion (I also had to remove the `e2` from the `DELETE` clause).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely get the question, but here is a stab at an answer. I believe that you want to delete all instances of the nodes labelled `TypeX`, which means you need to start by finding them all.

The current solutions are only matching the nodes when they appear in the middle of certain patterns. Is that the requirement, or can the `TypeX` nodes exist at the edges of the graph?

I have modified your path match to find nodes related by multiple `TypeX` nodes (note the * in the `e1` match). Also we are not interested in joining nodes we're going to delete, so exclude them in the `WHERE` clause.

```
MATCH p=(c)-[e1*]-(a:TypeX)-[e2]-(b)
WHERE NOT (b:TypeX) AND NOT (c:TypeX)
```

I favour `MERGE` for creating the new relationship:

```
MERGE c-[:CONNECTED_TO]-b
```

And then delete all the relationships in the original path:

```
FOREACH (rel IN rels(p)| 
     DELETE rel)
```

Finally delete all instances of the original match:

```
WITH a
DELETE a
```

I believe this or a small variant of it will solve your problem. Complete:

```
MATCH p=(c)-[e1*]-(a:TypeX)-[e2]-(b)
WHERE NOT (b:TypeX) AND NOT (c:TypeX)
MERGE c-[:CONNECTED_TO]-b
FOREACH (rel IN rels(p)| 
     DELETE rel)
WITH a
DELETE a
```

**EDIT - Fix inadequate answer**

This suddenly became tremendously complicated, and I am sure it shouldn't be, I'm hoping someone will step in with a reduction on this approach:

```
MATCH p=(c)-[e1*]-(a:TypeX)-[e2]-(b)
WHERE NOT (b:TypeX) AND NOT (c:TypeX) AND ALL (node IN NODES(p) 
                                           WHERE node = c OR node = b OR node:TypeX)
MERGE c-[:CONNECTED_TO]-b
FOREACH (rel IN rels(p)| 
     DELETE rel)
WITH a
DELETE a
```

Now you have a `WHERE` clause that enforces a not of type constraint on the two ends of the path and then verifies that all intermediate nodes are of the correct 'type'. If there was a mechanism for matching on a sub-collection we could have forgone the `node =c OR node = b` component.

I found it marginally faster with this slightly more complex version, because it removes paths where the same node is visited more than once (the initial `WHERE` clause`).

```
MATCH p=(c)-[e1*]-(a:TypeX)-[e2]-(b)
WHERE ALL (n IN NODES(p) 
       WHERE 1=LENGTH(FILTER(m IN NODES(p) 
                             WHERE m=n)))
WITH p, a, c, b
WHERE NOT (b:TypeX) AND NOT (c:TypeX) AND ALL (node IN NODES(p) 
                                           WHERE node = c OR node = b OR node:TypeX)
MERGE c-[:CONNECTED_TO]-b
FOREACH (rel IN rels(p)| 
     DELETE rel)
WITH a
DELETE a
```

This would all be a bit more simple if the relationships had a type (and the type was not the same between the different nodes), that doesn't happen to be the case does it!?

**Speed improvements if you could**

Use labels on b and c (indexing help to the engine, plus removes some of the (as long no nodes are labelled both Foo and TypeX) where clause:

```
MATCH p=(c:Foo)-[e1*]-(a:TypeX)-[e2]-(b:Foo)
WHERE ALL (node IN NODES(p) 
                WHERE node = c OR node = b OR node:TypeX)
```

Constrain the number of possible hops in e1, this will reduce the number of matches and therefore the amount of work having to be done in the filter:

```
MATCH p=(c)-[e1*1..2]-(a:TypeX)-[e2]-(b)
WHERE NOT (b:TypeX) AND NOT (c:TypeX) AND ALL (node IN NODES(p) 
                                       WHERE node = c OR node = b OR node:TypeX)
```

And if the relationships have different types you can gain efficiency by using the types in the `MATCH`:

```
MATCH p=(c)-[e1:OLD_REL_FOO_TO_X*]-(a:TypeX)-[e2::OLD_REL_FOO_TO_X]-(b)
WHERE NOT (b:TypeX) AND NOT (c:TypeX) AND ALL (node IN NODES(p) 
                                           WHERE node = c OR node = b OR node:TypeX)
```

And there will be more depending on your exact data. Obviously do all three if you can, but each will yield benefits.

Comment: I think that looks great, thanks.  Does the first `MATCH` clause guarantee that *all* the nodes in the path between `c` and `b` are `TypeX` nodes?  Or just the node closest to `b`?

Comment: Based on my testing it looks like it will also match non-`TypeX` nodes between `c` and `b` - if I could force them to only be `TypeX` nodes, I think this would be perfect.

Comment: You're quite right, I'll be back at my computer soon to revise, bad show!

Comment: Excellent, that solution does indeed do the trick.  I understand all of the pieces here except the optimization filter - is that part necessary if I have an acyclic graph?  (My graph right now can actually contain cycles, but I have another task to eliminate cycles.)

Comment: It's not really necessary, nope. For short paths it is cheaper than the second where clause and reduces calls to the second where clause. It also reduces superfluous called to `MERGE`. For longer paths it might be more expensive. The end result should be the same as going through the same node twice should still end up in the same place!

Comment: Unfortunately the query has been running for 30 minutes on my data, pegging the CPU, and I had to kill it before it finished.  By contrast, the Java-based one in my other answer runs in a couple seconds.  My graph has about 15,000 nodes total.

Comment: Yeah, the java solution will always win (for now). If this is a one time job, is there any reason to do everything in a single transaction? Can you put bounds on either the length of the e1 match, the types of c and b or the types of e1 or e2, all of those things will give you huge performance benefits.

Comment: I had the same thought - I tried to limit the length of the `e1` match to 1, i.e. just remove the star, but it still runs forever.  I'd also tried to add a `LIMIT` clause to the matching, but I couldn't figure out where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution I've gotten to work, using the Java API to delete one node at a time.  It's obviously a lot more verbose than a Cypher query!

```
    // 'db' is a 'GraphDatabaseService' object here
    Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
    String type = "TypeX";
    String relType = "CONNECTS_TO";

    Label toEliminate = DynamicLabel.label(type);

    List<String> toDelete = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Node n : GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodesWithLabel(toEliminate))
        toDelete.add((String) n.getProperty("id"));

    String query = "MATCH (c)-[e1]-(a:" + type +
       " {id:{id}})-[e2]-(b) MERGE c-[:" + relType + "]-b DELETE a, e1, e2";

    ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(db);
    for (String nodeId : toDelete) {
        engine.execute(query, MapUtil.map("id", nodeId));
    }

    tx.success();
    tx.close();
```

Comment: Does this handle transitive relationships? If you're happy with this approach, why not just two statements, one which deletes/creates the new relationships and another which just does `MATCH (x:TypeX) DELETE x`? Take the * out of my very first answer and it will work the same as this java code.

Comment: This *does* handle transitive relationships, which is why it's *not* the same as your approach.  The difference is that in this code, each operation operates on the result of the previous operation, whereas in the 2-query Cypher approach, each node's operation sees only the beginning state of the graph.

Comment: I get it, missed the for loop. Two query cypher approach would still achieve it, java will probably still be faster and hey, if it works and you've only got to do it once!

Comment: Agreed - just trying to use this problem as a learning exercise for how to write good/efficient queries, I'm pretty new to Cypher & Neo4j.